# Broken image URL on "Improved Question Merging"

Tags: bug, blog

When browsing on mobile, clicking on one of the images for the "[Improved Question Merging](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/06/10/improved-question-merging/)" blog post leads to a dead link.

[image: image with bad hyperlink]

Clicking this image leads to a 404 with the following URL.

https://stackoverflow.blog/images/wordpress/question-merge-example.png

Comment: Yeah, something went wrong when they moved the blogs (again) to use WordPress.